# fix javascript error in webbrowser?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wonder if there is any way to fix javascript errors that occur when using the `webbrowser` in `vb.net`, I do not want to hide "WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True" as the error causes the page stop working properly, I use `internet explorer 11` and `visual studio 2010`, I searched how to fix it and all I've found are people saying they use the WebKit alternatively. Visual studio 2013 solves this problem?, or I must give up the contanstes errors the webbrowser?

added: the site I'm visiting works completely fine in internet explorer, but the webbrowser shows several script errors, I have no access to the site I'm visiting, besides the javascript error is very consistent in several pages of the current I I tried using the webbrowser, especially pages like instagram, twitter, youtube. etc.

Comment: `Webbrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True` is the solution that i have used or you can use firefox's dll [geckofx](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) and the tutrorial is [here](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/12/how-to-make-web-browse-using-geckofx-on.html)

Comment: IE suppresses the errors by default.

Comment: I have software that is not my own, but is made in vb.net, and it works great with any web, what I've noticed is that when you open a process called browser.exe runs, there is no way to fix this problem without being installing third-party dll?